# Running Cukes in Parallel with JRuby

Tags: cucumber, jruby, celluloid

I'm trying to run cucumber scenarios in parallel from inside my gem.  From other answers, I've found I can execute cucumber scenarios with the following:

```
runtime = Cucumber::Runtime.new
runtime.load_programming_language('rb')
@result = Cucumber::Cli::Main.new(['features\my_feature:20']).execute!(runtime)
```

The above code works fine when I run one scenario at a time, but when I run them in parallel using something like Celluloid or Peach, I get Ambiguous Step errors.  It seems like my step definitions are being loaded for each parallel test and cucumber thinks I have multiple steps definitions of the same kind.

Any ideas how I can run these things in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber is not thread safe.  Each scenario must be run in a separate thread with it's own cucumber runtime.  Celluloid may try to run multiple scenarios on the same actor at the same time.

There is a project called [cukeforker](https://github.com/jarib/cukeforker) that can run scenarios in parallel but it only supports mri on linux and osx.  It forks a subprocess per scenario.

I've created a fork of cukeforker called [jcukeforker](https://github.com/jesg/jcukeforker) that supports both mri and jruby on linux.  Jcukeforker will distribute scenarios to subprocesses.  The subprocesses are reused.  Subprocesses are used instead of threads to guarantee that each test has it's own global variables.  This is important when running the subprocess on a vncserver which requires the DISPLAY variable to be set.